# Why Does the Ubuntu Basic Security Page Say Not to use Firefox's Hardware Acceleration?

Tags: firefox, security, hardware-acceleration

Is hardware acceleration not secure? Is this statement old?

Ubuntu Wiki Basic Security Page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

Comment: Good point. I can't think of a reason other than having GPU active may increase the "surface area" exposed to attackers. Search the internet for "hackers exploiting gpu vulnerability" and you'll get several hits.